# Remove Rows by Max Date

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Date Pulled         Date      Col3   Col4
2019-01-19     2019-01-17        8      9
2019-01-19     2019-01-18       14      9
2019-01-20     2019-01-18        8      0
2019-01-20     2019-01-18       15     14
2019-01-18     2019-01-17       18      7
```

I want to write the logic stating -

Whenever `Date Pulled` has a different value AND given that `Date Pulled` values are different, the corresponding `Date` values are the same in that column, I want to only keep the row with the max value from `Date Pulled`.

```
Date Pulled         Date      Col3   Col4
2019-01-19     2019-01-17        8      9
2019-01-20     2019-01-18        8      0
2019-01-20     2019-01-18       15     14
```

For context, I am pulling in data daily that has 7 days everytime. If I rbind the results together, there are going to be duplicate dates (hence duplicate Date columns). I want to only keep the most recent report I pull in hence the max Date Pulled.

Comment: I made the question more clear, let me know if this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the 'Col1' and 'Col2' are `Date` class, grouped by 'Col2' and `filter` the rows where the 'Col1' is equal to `max` of 'Col1'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Col2) %>% 
    filter((Col1 == max(Col1) )
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Col2 [2]
#  Col1       Col2        Col3  Col4
#  <date>     <date>     <int> <int>
#1 2019-01-19 2019-01-17     8     9
#2 2019-01-20 2019-01-18     8     0
#3 2019-01-20 2019-01-18    15    14
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(17915, 17915, 17916, 17916, 
17914), class = "Date"), Col2 = structure(c(17913, 17914, 17914, 
17914, 17913), class = "Date"), Col3 = c(8L, 14L, 8L, 15L, 18L
), Col4 = c(9L, 9L, 0L, 14L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this doesn't work though because it is grouping it by day even though there are instances where duplicates are allowed

Comment: @nak5120  I edited the post.  May be this logic works for you

Answer (score 1):

> I want to only keep the most recent report I pull in hence the max Date Pulled.

This seems to work:

```
inner_join(
  DT, 
  DT %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Pulled = max(Pulled))
)

Joining, by = c("Pulled", "Date")
      Pulled       Date Col3 Col4
1 2019-01-19 2019-01-17    8    9
2 2019-01-20 2019-01-18    8    0
3 2019-01-20 2019-01-18   15   14
```

where

```
DT = structure(list(Pulled = c("2019-01-19", "2019-01-19", "2019-01-20", 
"2019-01-20", "2019-01-18"), Date = c("2019-01-17", "2019-01-18", 
"2019-01-18", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-17"), Col3 = c(8L, 14L, 
8L, 15L, 18L), Col4 = c(9L, 9L, 0L, 14L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

(That is, I did not bother converting to date class.)